# GSSAPI Error: Miscellaneous failure (see text (Error from KDC: PROCESS_TGS) after upgrading to the MacOs BigSur

Tags: python, macos, hive, kerberos

Before BigSur version, I could easily connect to the impala via kerberos authenticaiton. But right now I am getting the error when I run this script:

```py
from impala.dbapi import connect

conn = connect(host='test123', port=21050,auth_mechanism='GSSAPI',kerberos_service_name='impala')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('show tables')
print(cursor.description)
results = cursor.fetchall()
for p in results:
     print(p)
```

Error is

```
thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=1, message="Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-1) SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (Error from KDC: PROCESS_TGS)'")
```

I see the ticket via `$ klist`

```
Ticket cache: KCM:13956728
Default principal: *****

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
01/14/2021 16:31:30  01/15/2021 02:31:30  krbtgt/****
        renew until 01/21/2021 16:31:27
```

I also tested the connection to test123 via telnet and there was no problem.

Comment: I still can not connect :((

Comment: Python script sometimes can run without an error. However most of the time still can not run the script. Very interesting  issue ...